# How to get rid of warnings about mixed content downloads in Microsoft edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Half of the times I click on a PDF link in MS Edge, the browser tries to stop be from getting the article I want. I have to click through two confirmations. Very annoying, and easy to click on the wrong button.

Is it possible to tell Edge I’m totally fine downloading unencrypted publicly hosted content?

Maybe there’s some group policy setting, or registry parameter?

Comment: Note that Mixed content vulnerabilities in pages you use can be quite a serious issue, and may expose the protected elements of the page to attackers who can intercept and mangle the unsecured content, allowing tricks like logging passwords and personal information, even if those elements are served using a secure protocol.

Comment: @FrankThomas I only care about these security issues on login pages. Login pages is like 0.1% of my internet traffic, the rest of the traffic is public content. Crippling 99.9% of pages to secure the remaining 0.1% was not a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

People claim that you can disable the "mixed content setting" in IE an that that will disable the prompt in Edge.

Internet Options, Security Settings / Internet Zones / Display Mixed Content